# What counts as an academic affiliation for arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

Is it just being enrolled at a university with a recognized school email address?

Answer (score 2):

arXiv states (step 2 of registration):

> Claimed affiliation should be current in the conventional sense: e.g., physical presence, funding, email address, mention on institutional web pages, etc.

arXiv's notion of *conventional sense* seems peculiar. They omit perhaps the most common *conventional* notion of affiliation: employee. Other common notions -- e.g., those involving some written agreement -- are also omitted. (Perhaps arXiv want ties beyond employment or perhaps this was an oversight.)

Comment: My question is whether you need all of those qualifications. For example, if I have an email, a physical presence, and a mention on the institutional web page, but no funding, is this acceptable? Does the statement imply needing all of the qualifications, or some?

Comment: @TejasRao It's unclear what _funding_ means in this instance. It could mean salary, but funding is a peculiar choice of synonym, so perhaps it means grant associated with the affiliation. Given that many researchers -- including most PhD students -- don't have funding, you can assume that it isn't required. More generally, you don't need to satisfy all of those criterion. Thus, a part-time researcher without physical presence, but with an email address and mention on institutional web pages, would be considered as affiliation.